# Ethereum Test Account not Showing Ethers

Tags: ethereum, ether

I just installed Ethereum wallet as I wanted to try out the Ethereum platform. I created an account and connected to the test network RINKEBY. I used the following faucet to send me some test ethers:

faucet.ropsten.de:3001

It says that it has dispatched me 3 Ether's but I could never see them in my wallet. Here is a screenshot of the wallet:

[image]

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a customer service issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another site on the Stack Exchange Network. Try https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a third-party customer service issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Ether from Rinkeby test Network:

Follow the steps for add a free test network - Ether to your wallet:

1. copy a address of your Wallet(Eather wallet/Metamask)
2. open this  : http://rinkeby-faucet.com/
3. Add your address to this link.

And finally you get free Ether for your test Wallet.